# how to ignore iframe on blade Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

#Asking

Help me for my problem, when i built a website with Laravel

i am render my post with syntax like this :

```
<div>
  <p>{!! $post->content !!}</p>
</div>
```

but i have problem, when i insert a `i frame` inside post, because the html has been removed with `{!! !!}`.

i have to try use `{{ $post->content }}`, but all content rendered with HTML

Any solution to this problem? ?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `{!!` you paste content "as is", in other words you become vulnerable to all types of issues like allowing `<script>` tags to be placed into your templates.

The `{{` syntax will escape any HTML thus what you see is the actual html characters without actually parsing it (i.e. doing `{{ '<b>bold</b>' }}` will not result in a bold font but in the text `<b>bold</b>`).

Now with your problem: there are some cumbersome ways to filter out any html tags yourself and leave the `<iframe>`'s in there (something like `{!! only_iframe($content) !!}`), but it is quite difficult and will likely not result in a safe solution.

Your own answer which stated that you used `{!!html_entity_decode($post->content)!!}` simply means that your HTML was encoded to start with, which is not something I can deduct from your question. Note that you are now vulnerable to malicious code injection if you are not certain you can control the contents of `$post->content`.